# how to manage people that can access to folders in SharePoint using API

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, permissions

i am trying to use SharePoint API to manage people that can access to some specifics folders , is it possible ?
thanks for your help and your time <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Rest API in order to break inheritance/delete unique assignments, add permissions to unique users or groups.
You can check out some examples on this [link](https://sharepointcass.com/2021/04/22/sharepoint-online-rest-apis-part-vi-permissions/).

You can also use Power Automate SharePoint Connector Actions in order to achieve the same result. Here are some of the actions you can take:

- [Grant access to an item or a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#grant-access-to-an-item-or-a-folder)
- [Stop sharing an item or a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#stop-sharing-an-item-or-a-file)
- [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint) (this action can be used in order to achieve composite results)

I hope these were some of the options that you were looking for.